# how to affix div at top when we scroll down in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uaa3U/1087/)  , i want to fixed the `nav-pills` div if users scroll down.
I tried with below code, but it seems not working as i wanted.

```
 $(function() {
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
    });
  });
```

---

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please reply, if my question is not clear

Comment: It is not clear, the navbar already looks fixed at the top initially. Do you want it somewhere in the middle initially and fix it when the user scrolls down to its level ?

Comment: @sinanspd  am not saying navbar to fixed,  I want to fix the div  with `id="nav"` in my example, if user scroll down... please check example with div id="nav"  , you will come to know what i am asking for

Comment: @sinanspd http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv9oB.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) functions together to learn the position of an element when scrolling. Using this, you can create the behaviour you want. I changed your fiddle to get it to work like what I understand you want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uaa3U/1091/)

```
var originalPos;
$(document).on("scroll", function(e){
    if($("#nav-wrapper").hasClass("affixed")){
        if($(document).scrollTop() <= originalPos)
            $("#nav-wrapper").removeClass("affixed");
        return;
    }

    if((originalPos = $(document).scrollTop()) >= ($("#nav-wrapper").offset().top - $("#nav-wrapper").height())){
        $("#nav-wrapper").addClass("affixed");
    }
})
```